# Return instance of generic class from method in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a template class:

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : IConvertible {}
```

And derived classes:

```
public enum Vals1{}

public class Der1: Base<Vals1> {}


public enum Vals2{}

public class Der2: Base<Vals2> {}
```

I want to write a method that returns instance of `Der1` or `Der2` but I don't know which.

I tried something like this:

```
private Base<T> GetDer() where T : IConvertible
{
    if (condition)
        return new Der1();
    return new Der2();
}
```

But I get errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Der1' to 'Base<T>'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Der2' to 'Base<T>'
```

Casting doesn't help either. It returns the same error, just without word "implicitly".

Is there a way to do what I want simply or do I have to find some other more strenuous way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `return new Der1() as Base<T>;` / `return (Base<T>)new Der1()`

Comment: so it is really `GetDer<T>`, and you want to special-case when `T` is `Vals1` or `Vals2` ? That's *possible*, but: any particular reason? and what should `GetDer<T>` do when `T` is `int` or `string`? (by which I mean: something that isn't one of the things you handle)? if you need to hard-code every `T`, it *probably shouldn't be generic*

Comment: `Vals1` and `Vals2` are essentially 2 different types, therefore `Base<Vals1` and `Base<Vals2>` cannot be used in the same method, you would have to use `object` as the return type for that as its the only common ancestor or the generic *instances*. Otherwise i suggest moving your condition out of the method, then have the method as a generic, operating purely on one type parameter `<T>` at a time.

Comment: You don't have a template class, you have a generic class. A bit nit-picky I'll admit but the two are very different things. Probably this is where your confusion is coming from.

Comment: @gerryc.inc I *think* the method is *meant* to be generic `GetDer<T>()`; otherwise the `where T : IConvertible` makes no sense

Comment: @NibblyPig I tried both with no succes @Marc_Gravell T can only be Vals1 or Vals2. As for `GetDer<T>` I would have to know what is T while calling method, which I don't @gerryc.inc Yes, I thought about object but didn't want to use it, bacause I would still need to check later whether it is `Der1` or `Der1` and won't be able to use a method from Base<T>

Answer (score 0):

If you create an additional `Base` class which is not generic, then you could inherit `Base<T>` from it.

```cs
public abstract class Base {}

public abstract class Base<T> : Base where T : IConvertible {}
```

Then your method becomes:

```cs
private Base GetDer()
{
    if (condition)
        return new Der1();
    return new Der2();
}
```

This is about finding or adding a common ancestor in the inheritance hierarchy (that is not `object`...). Of course, you lose information this way because you lose type information when calling `GetDer()`.

- If the methods you wish to call later on your returned object do not require a value for `T`, then you should move those methods up from `Base<T>` to the `Base` class so that you can still use them.
- If the methods you wish to call require a defined `T`, then I don't see another way than using some reflection to deduce the type of `T` at run-time or using the `dynamic` keyword to by-pass compile-time checks:

```cs
public abstract class Base<T> : Base where T : IConvertible {
    abstract void MethodFromBaseT();
}

...

dynamic myObject = GetDer();
myObject.MethodFromBaseT(); //does compile
```

Note that you have to use `dynamic` because the returned type is basically unknown, because as said in the comments, two different `Base<T>` with different `T` are two distinct types that do not inherit each other.